# Jquery - Flot, How can I only show points and not lines?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, flot

Okay to get started I am using Jquery-Flot to plot a radial graph I have found a plug in to create a spider graph see API here:

http://www.jumware.com/Includes/jquery/Flot/Doc/JQuery.Flot.spider.html

Now it works all nicely bar the fact I dont want to show the lines that connect the points.
Usually with:

```
points: { show: true}, lines: { show: false}
```

but when using the spider plugin it seems to ignore this setting. Am I doing something wrong here or is it a case of when using this plugin I have to show lines?

---

Working example at:

http://jsfiddle.net/WAscC/2/

---

Code:

```
function EveryOneSec() {

    var d1 = [[0, 10], [1, 20], [2, 80], [3, 70], [4, 60]];
    var d2 = [[0, 30], [1, 25], [2, 50], [3, 60], [4, 95]];
    var d3 = [[0, 50], [1, 40], [2, 60], [3, 95], [4, 30]];

    var options = {
        series: {
            spider: {
                active: true,
                legs: {
                    data: ["", "", "", "", ""],
                    legScaleMax: 1,
                    legScaleMin: 0.8
                }, spiderSize: 0.9
            }
        }, grid: {
            hoverable: false,
            clickable: false,
            tickColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)",
            mode: "radar"
        }
    };


    data = [{
        label: "",
        data: d1,
        spider: {
            show: true,
            lineWidth: 0
        }
    }, {
        label: "",
        data: d2,
        spider: {
            show: true,
            lineWidth: 0
        }
    }, {
        label: "",
        data: d3,
        spider: {
            show: true,
            lineWidth: 0
        },
        points: { show: true},lines: { show: false }
    }];

    $.plot($("#RadialPlot"), data, options);
}
EveryOneSec();
```

---

**Update One**

editing `lineWidth: 0,
                connectionWidth: 0` to any number seems to have no affect at all on the graph.

---

**How can I only show points and not lines?**

Comment: played around a bit with the script ... if you leave out the spider-options it works ... interesting ...

Comment: Which spider-options as in leaving it as a plain flot without plugin?

Comment: i've meant the whole `spider:`-section ...

Comment: Yes. If it isn't set as a spider graph it works :( fustrating.

Comment: i believe this is the feature of the `spider`-graph ... i don't believe this cooperation between the extension `spider` and the library is not implemented... see http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=138 (original request of this extension) ... you might go for the project site ...

Comment: "see code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=138" - Is my comments with the links.

Comment: ^^ ... oh .. groo found a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `connection: { width: 0 }` to spider options:

```
spider: {
   active: true,
   connection: { width: 0 }, // add this line
   legs: {
       data: ["", "", "", "", ""],
       legScaleMax: 1,
       legScaleMin: 0.8
   },
   spiderSize: 0.9
}
```

[Documentation](http://www.jumware.com/Includes/jquery/Flot/Doc/JQuery.Flot.Spider.html) states that option should be: `connectionWidth: 0`, but that seems to have changed, as seen from the [source for the actual plugin](http://www.jumware.com/Includes/jquery/Flot/JS/JQuery.Flot.Spider.js):

```
function drawspiderConnections(ctx,cnt,serie,c,fill) {
    var pos,d;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = serie.spider.connection.width; // this is the line

    // etc.

}
```

Comment: I tried adding that in below spiderSize didnt work :S did exactly as you did and it does. Thankyou fine sir.